# Now to allow source IP do specific port

Tags: firewall, nftables

I want to allow IP `1.2.3.4` on port 3306 with nftables, but I was not able to find how to actually insert port?

I was trying something like `nft insert saddr 1.2.3.4.5 ip daddr server_ip accept`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I assume it's the MySQL port, using the TCP protocol:

`sudo nft add rule filter input ip saddr 1.2.3.4 tcp dport 3306 accept`

The `saddr` and `daddr` options are part of `ip` setting, while the `sport` and `dport` options should be used with the layer 4 protocol such as `tcp` or `udp`.